# How to make a pop up button (Python)

Tags: python

How would I make it it so a pop up box (If you have better name for it comment below) appear asking you a question. It would have one button saying I agree and another saying I disagree.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked up the `tkinter` module?

Comment: I did google it for a while, but i didn't really understand, i am newish to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a simple one I suppose:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
questionsAsked = []

def yes():
    #do stuff if the user says yes
    pass

def no():
    #do stuff if the user says no
    pass

def modal(question):
    if question in questionsAsked:
        return False
    questionsAsked.append(question)

    label = tk.Label(root, text=question)

    bYes = tk.Button(root, text="Yes", command=yes)
    bNo = tk.Button(root, text="No", command=no)

    for el in [label, bYes, bNo]:
        el.pack()

modal("Do you want to continue?")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would you make it so it only asks it once (thanks for the help!)

Comment: What do you mean by “only asks once”? Do you mean the same question can’t be asked multiple times? Or do you mean that the window closes after the user selects an option?

Comment: Hmmm...I would probably need to see more of your code to make it work, but I’ll put an example up.